# How to use INTERVAL and a database field in SqlAlchemy with a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, subquery

I am trying to call this query in SQLAlchemy against a MySQL database:

```
   select date_format(a.Date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as dateTime
   from (
      select curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) ) HOUR as Date
      from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
      cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
      cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
      cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
   ) a
   where a.Date between '2023–09-20' and '2023-11-04'
```

I have created the cross_join subqueries, and the outmost query as such:

```
                crossjoin_subquery_a = (
                    union_all((select(literal_column('0').label('num'))), (select(literal_column('1'))), (select(literal_column('2'))), (select(literal_column('3'))), (select(literal_column('4'))), (select(literal_column('5'))), (select(literal_column('6'))), (select(literal_column('7'))), (select(literal_column('8'))), (select(literal_column('9'))))
                ).subquery()
                crossjoin_subquery_b = (
                    union_all((select(literal_column('0').label('num'))), (select(literal_column('1'))), (select(literal_column('2'))), (select(literal_column('3'))), (select(literal_column('4'))), (select(literal_column('5'))), (select(literal_column('6'))), (select(literal_column('7'))), (select(literal_column('8'))), (select(literal_column('9'))))
                ).subquery()
                crossjoin_subquery_c = (
                    union_all((select(literal_column('0').label('num'))), (select(literal_column('1'))), (select(literal_column('2'))), (select(literal_column('3'))), (select(literal_column('4'))), (select(literal_column('5'))), (select(literal_column('6'))), (select(literal_column('7'))), (select(literal_column('8'))), (select(literal_column('9'))))
                ).subquery()
                crossjoin_subquery_d = (
                    union_all((select(literal_column('0').label('num'))), (select(literal_column('1'))), (select(literal_column('2'))), (select(literal_column('3'))), (select(literal_column('4'))), (select(literal_column('5'))), (select(literal_column('6'))), (select(literal_column('7'))), (select(literal_column('8'))), (select(literal_column('9'))))
                ).subquery()
                # create_dates_subquery = goes here
                date_subquery = (
                    select(
                        func.date_format(create_dates_subquery.c.date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00").label("dateTime"))
                    .where(create_dates_subquery.c.date >= startTime)
                    .where(create_dates_subquery.c.date < endTime)
                )
```

For the create_dates_subquery, I cannot figure out how use the INTERVAL in conjunction with a subquery field. From everything I've seen thus far, SQLAlchemy only supports the INTERVAL type on PostgresSQL and Oracle. Since this is a MySQL database, this isn't helpful. So the other solutions are to use text(), usually like text('INTERVAL 1 DAY'). But since I'm attempting to calculate the number portion of the interval from fields, using text is problematic.

This solution works:

```
                create_dates_subquery = (
                    select(crossjoin_subquery_a.c.num, crossjoin_subquery_b.c.num, crossjoin_subquery_c.c.num, crossjoin_subquery_d.c.num,
                        (func.curdate() -
                                      text("interval (" +
                                           "anon_2.num" +
                                           " + (10 * " +
                                           "anon_3.num" +
                                           ") + (100 * " +
                                           "anon_4.num" +
                                           ") + (1000 * " +
                                           "anon_5.num" +
                                           ")) hour")).label('date')
                    )
                )
```

But it is dependent on SQLAlchemy's naming of subqueries as anon_#.

Is there a better way?